# 7zip zip multiple folders to multiple archive incrementally on windows

Tags: windows, 7-zip

i have batch file contains the following command

```
cd /D C:\xampp\htdocs\phpPgAdmin-5.1
FOR %%A IN (*.*) DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7za.exe" a -t7z "D:\7zbackup\%%~nA.7z" "%%A"
```

but the above command only zip the files in phpPgAdmin-5.1 but not include directories and also i also want to add incremental features to the command just like (but this only for one archive)

```
start /d "C:\Program Files\7-Zip" 7z.exe u -ms=off "D:\7zbackup\htdocs.7z" "C:\xampp\htdocs\*"
```